# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. when trying to connect to the database server

Tags: c#, database-connection

I got this error when trying to connect to the database server

> "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

here is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=myServer;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True");

            con.Open();

            Console.WriteLine(con.State);

            con.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(con.State);

            Console.ReadKey();
```

I want to know the root cause of this error

Comment: There is nothing in the code shown that should cause this issue. Does that code **by itself** cause this? Also: what .NET version are you using?

Comment: @MarcGravell,  i have visual studio 2010(.net 4.0) installed on my pc, then yesterday i installed visual studio 2013(.net 4.5.1), my program works only if i comment out that piece of code.

Comment: Is this all the code you're using? As @MarcGravell mentioned, there isn't anything in this specific code snippet that could cause this exception, and we can't guess what your environment is like.